# How to Aggregate and Sum in Python (or R) with a Specific Condition

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, dplyr

**Objective**

I have a dataset, df, that I would like to group the length column, take its sum, and display the endtime that's associated with it:

```
 length start                      end                      duration
 6330   12/17/2019 10:34:23 AM     12/17/2019 10:34:31 AM   8
 57770  12/19/2019 5:19:56 PM      12/17/2019 5:24:19 PM    263
 6330   12/17/2019 10:34:54 AM     12/17/2019 10:35:00 AM   6
 6330   12/18/2019 4:36:44 PM      12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM    29
 57770  12/19/2019 5:24:47 PM      12/19/2019 5:26:44 PM    117
```

**Desired Output**

```
length  end                     total Duration
6330    12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM   43  
57770   12/19/2019 5:26:44 PM   380
```

**Dput**

```
structure(list(length = c(6330L, 57770L, 6330L, 6330L, 57770L
), start = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("12/17/2019 10:34:23 AM", 
"12/17/2019 10:34:54 AM", "12/18/2019 4:36:44 PM", "12/19/2019 5:19:56 PM", 
"12/19/2019 5:24:47 PM"), class = "factor"), end = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("12/17/2019 10:34:31 AM", "12/17/2019 10:35:00 AM", 
"12/17/2019 5:24:19 PM", "12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM", "12/19/2019 5:26:44 PM"
), class = "factor"), duration = c(8L, 263L, 6L, 29L, 117L)), class = "data.frame", row.names =    c(NA, 
-5L))
```

This is what I have tried:, but how do I also display the end column that's associated with the 'latest' length value?
For instance, length, 6330 has 3 end values, with 3 durations attached to it:

```
           12/17/2019 10:34:31 AM            8
           12/17/2019 10:35:00 AM            6
           12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM            29


12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM is the latest end time, so I would like to output the end time, 
along with the sum of durations for this particular length value.
```

**Desired Output**

```
length  end                     total Duration
6330    12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM   43  
57770   12/19/2019 5:26:44 PM   380
```

**This is what I have tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = df.groupby('length')['duration'].sum()
```

However, it only outputs the length and total duration. How would I output the length, the latest end
as well as the total duration for that particular length?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure there are a million answers about something like this, but basically: `df.groupby('length').agg({'duration' : 'sum', 'end' : 'max'}).reset_index()`.  And if you wanted to you can do `.agg({'end' : ['max','min']})` etc. etc.  Pretty much endless possibilities.

Comment: Oh I see @elPastor I am still gaining knowledge with Python. I will have to try this. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, that's very specifically a _pandas_ function (as opposed to pure python), but I hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying this now. I hope so thank you

Comment: This works @elPastor - maybe you can post this as the answer because it works thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `R`, we can group by 'length', use `summarise` and get the `sum` of 'duration' and extract the `max` element of 'end' after converting to DateTime class with `mdy_hms` (from `lubridate`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   group_by(length) %>% 
   summarise(duration = sum(duration), end = end[which.max(mdy_hms(end))])
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas we can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for this, but we have two choices here:

1. simple dicationary aggregation:

```
df.groupby('length').agg({'duration': 'sum', 'end': 'max'}).reset_index()

   length  duration                 end
0    6330        43 2019-12-18 16:37:13
1   57770       380 2019-12-19 17:26:44
```

---

2. [Named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html)s, renaming columns while aggregating:

*new since `pandas 0.25.0+`*

```
df.groupby('length').agg(
    end=('end', 'max'),
    total_duration=('duration', 'sum')
).reset_index()

   length                 end  total_duration
0    6330 2019-12-18 16:37:13              43
1   57770 2019-12-19 17:26:44             380
```

---

Note: dont forget to convert your date columns to datetime before:

```
df[['start', 'end']] = (
    df[['start', 'end']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format=True))
)
```

Comment: `infer_datetime_format = True` in `pd.to_datetime()` for a massive improvement in speed assuming a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

In R, it can be done using some `tidyverse` libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~length,~start,~end,~duration,
6330,"12/17/2019 10:34:23 AM","12/17/2019 10:34:31 AM",8,
57770,"12/19/2019 5:19:56 PM","12/17/2019 5:24:19 PM",263,
6330,"12/17/2019 10:34:54 AM","12/17/2019 10:35:00 AM",6,
6330,"12/18/2019 4:36:44 PM","12/18/2019 4:37:13 PM",29,
57770,"12/19/2019 5:24:47 PM","12/19/2019 5:26:44 PM",117
) %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(start, end),
    lubridate::mdy_hms
  )

df %>% 
  group_by(length) %>% 
  summarise(
    end = max(end, na.rm = TRUE),
    duration = sum(duration, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  length end                 duration
   <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1   6330 2019-12-18 16:37:13       43
2  57770 2019-12-19 17:26:44      380
```

Timestamps are formatted in ISO format.

I have used the default TZ (UTC) when converting the values.